# The code will print i after the conditions, but it won't print the sum of i. Error states that 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = int(input("Pick one small number: "))
y = int(input("And a bigger number: "))

if x > y:
    print ("Doesn't work. ")

elif x < y:

    for i in range(x,y):
        if i%7 == 0 and i%5 !=0:
            z = sum(i)
            print (z)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `z = sum(i)`.

Comment: The issue is that an integer is not iterable. The `sum` function can take in iterable objects like an array of integers, a tuple of integers, etc., not a single integer, or comma separated integers.

Comment: Maybe you want `z = sum(i for i in range(x, y) if i % 7 == 0 and i % 5 != 0)`? Or just use `z = 0 ... z += i` to sum i one at a time

Comment: Please provide some more context in your post rather than just your program (just the title doesn't cover it all!).

Comment: Like what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Sum the numbers between `x` and `y` that are divisible by both 7 and 5?

Comment: The small field labelled "Title" is for a short description *only*. A full question should go in the (much) larger field. Make sure to include the full error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to sum `i` one at a time like this:

```
z = 0
for n in range(x,y):
    if n%7 == 0 and n%5 !=0:
        n += i
        print("Running total:", z)
print("Final total:", z)
```

If you want to use `sum` instead you have to apply it to a list:

```
filtered_list = []
for n in range(x,y):
    if n % 7 == 0 and n % 5 !=0:
        filtered_list.append(n)
print("Final total:", sum(filtered_list))
```

or using a generator expression:

```
print(sum(n for n in range(x, y) if n%7 == 0 and n%5 !=0))
```

There is also a shortcut to get all the multiples of 7 within `range(x, y)` :

```
multiples = range(x + 7 - x % 7, y, 7)
```

Then you only have to check the second condition (not divisible by 5)

```
print(sum(n for n in multiples if n%5 !=0))
```

You could also create 2 sets and calculate the difference:

```
def multiples(start, stop, d):
    """ This function returns the set of all multiples of d between start and stop """
    return set(range(start + divisor - start % divisor, stop, divisor))

print(sum(multiples(x, y, 7) - multiples(x, y, 5))
```

Finally a more maths approach. Your `if` condition is selecting the multiples of 7 and filtering out the numbers that are multiples of both 5 and 7. This is equivalent to subtracting the sum of the multiples of the least common multiple of 5 and 7 (which is 35) from the sum of the multiples of 7 within the range...

```
# we need a function from the math module that calculates the greatest common denominator
# we will use this to help calculate the least common multiple
from math import gcd 

def sum_of_multiples(start, stop, mult):
    """ Calculate sum of multiples of mult that lie in the range start, stop """
    start //= mult
    stop //= mult
    return mult * (stop - start) * (stop + start + 1) / 2

lcm = 5 * 7 // gcd(5, 7)   # The least common multiple of 5 and 7 = 35
print("Total:", sum_of_multiples(x, y, 7) - sum_of_multiples(x, y, lcm))
```

(Of course in the above you could just write 35 instead of `lcm`. I show the calculation in case you want to apply this using other numbers.)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use a generator expression to do what I needed, but I couldn't understand why this code wouldn't work. I think I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what an iterator is/how it should work. The generator expressions seems to use the same conditions?

Comment: `i` in your code takes one value at a time. So `sum(i)` when `i` is 1, is like saying "the sum of 1", which doesn't make sense. The `sum` function expects something like a list of numbers (an iterable). The generator expression represents an iterable that goes through the different numbers in the range that match the condition. See the [docs on list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (which are similar to generator expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that exception because sum expects an object that can be iterated through or in other words can return an iterator, such as a list, or tuple.

A proper way would have been to utilize the iterator object returned by the range function to get the cumulative value of all the numbers between x and y which are factors for  7 but not factors of 5.

```
x = int(input("Pick one small number: "))
y = int(input("And a bigger number: "))

if x > y:
    print ("Doesn't work. ")

elif x < y:
    print(sum([i for i in range(x, y) if i%7 == 0 and i%5 != 0]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use a generator expression to do what I needed, but I couldn't understand why this code wouldn't work. I think I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what an iterator is/how it should work.